# Axioms based on $\leftrightarrow, \lor, \bot$ for propositional intuitionistic logic?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, axioms, constructive-mathematics

Propositional intuitionistic logic can be axiomatized based on $\;\to, \land, \lor, \bot\;$, with modus ponens
$$
\text{from }\; \phi \;\text{ and }\; \phi \to \psi \;\text{ infer }\; \psi
$$
as the only inference rule, and a list of axioms like
$$
\phi \to (\chi \to \phi )
$$
See [the Wikipedia page on 'Intuitionistic logic' under 'Hilbert-style calculus'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic#Hilbert-style_calculus) for a complete list of axioms.

Now that same page also claims that "{∨, ↔, ⊥} and {∨, ↔, ¬} are complete bases of intuitionistic connectives."  And what I am looking for is a list of inference rules and axioms to back up Wikipedia's claim.

Strictly speaking this is of course simple: one can take the $\;\to, \land, \lor, \bot\;$ axioms, and replace every $\;\phi \to \psi\;$ by $\;(\phi \lor \psi) \leftrightarrow \psi\;$, and every $\;\phi \land \psi\;$ by $\;(\phi \lor \psi) \leftrightarrow (\phi \leftrightarrow \psi)\;$.  But the result is not very elegant.

I've been puzzling a bit on constructing a nicer axiomatization, and I think it should at least have the inference rule
$$
\text{from }\; \phi \;\text{ and }\; \phi \leftrightarrow \psi \;\text{ infer }\; \psi
$$
and axioms like
$$
(\phi \leftrightarrow \psi) \;\leftrightarrow\; (\psi \leftrightarrow \phi)
\\
(\phi \leftrightarrow (\chi \leftrightarrow \psi)) \;\leftrightarrow\; ((\phi \leftrightarrow \chi) \leftrightarrow \psi)
$$

Therefore my question is: What is a complete and elegant axiomatization of propositional intuitionistic logic based on $\;\leftrightarrow, \lor, \bot\;$?

Comment: There's always "define $\vee, \to$ in terms of those, and then use the nice axiomatization you already know".

Comment: @Hurkyl: That seems to be the point of the OP's "Strictly speaking ..." paragraph. I agree that the outcome of that would hardly be elegant.

Comment: Who says there's an elegant way to do it?

Comment: @dfeuer Nobody, as far as I know.  I'm _hoping_ there is an elegant way to do this.

Comment: Are you sure that $(\phi\land\psi)$ is _intuitionistically_ equivalent to $(\phi\lor\psi)\leftrightarrow(\phi\leftrightarrow\psi)$? It works classically, of course, but I don't see how one can derive $\phi$ from the latter intuitionistically.

Comment: You may find the sort of characterization you're looking for if you look into [Heyting algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heyting_algebra).

Comment: @HenningMakholm, I think you're right, but I don't know enough to *prove* it. I assume I need to find a Heyting algebra in which it does not hold? I'm trying to come up with something in the set of open sets of the real line, but even expanding the expression $(p\cup q)\leftrightarrow(p\leftrightarrow q)$ is proving to be a fairly long process and is not giving me anything that appears to have much hope of intuitive meaning susceptible to counterexample production.

Comment: @dfeuer: Kripke models may be easier. Since $\phi\equiv(A\lor B)\leftrightarrow(A\leftrightarrow B)$ has only two propositional variables, there are just four possible states of the world. And it doesn't seem to be possible to put together a frame where $\phi$ ever has a different value than $A\land B$, which IIRC should mean that this representation of $\land$ _is_ actually intuitionistically valid. It doesn't really produce a derivation of $A$ from $\phi$, though ...

Comment: @HenningMakholm, unfortunately you've now flown clear over my head. If it's intuitionistically valid, wouldn't that mean there has to be a derivation (which seems unlikely)?

Comment: @dfeuer: Yes, if it is valid, then there has to be a derivation. Unfortunately, brute-force checking the possible Kripke models doesn't help _find_ that derivation, even though (unless I'm misremembering how they work, which is possible) they imply that there must be one somewhere.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, $(p\land q)\equiv (((p\lor q)\iff p)\iff q)$, but I have no idea where that comes from either.

Comment: @dfeuer: I found a proof; see my answer.

Comment: I don't think that "↔" associates in intuitionist logic, does it?

Comment: Does Wikipedia's claim imply anything about the possibility of such an axiomatization, or just imply a claim about representability of connectives?

Answer (score 4):

How about a sequent calculus, with standard rules:

$$ \frac{\Gamma, P, P\vdash Q}{\Gamma, P\vdash Q}CL \qquad
\frac{}{\Gamma,P \vdash P}Ax  \qquad \frac{}{\Gamma, \bot \vdash P}{\bot}L $$
$$ \frac{\Gamma\vdash Q\quad \Gamma,P\vdash R}{\Gamma,P\leftrightarrow Q\vdash R}{\leftrightarrow}L_1
\quad \frac{\Gamma\vdash P\quad \Gamma,Q\vdash R}{\Gamma,P\leftrightarrow Q\vdash R}{\leftrightarrow}L_2
\quad \frac{\Gamma,P\vdash Q\quad \Gamma,Q\vdash P}{\Gamma\vdash P\leftrightarrow Q}{\leftrightarrow}R$$
$$ \frac{\Gamma,P\vdash R \quad \Gamma,Q\vdash R}{\Gamma,P\lor Q\vdash R}{\lor}L
\quad \frac{\Gamma\vdash P}{\Gamma\vdash P\lor Q}{\lor}R_1
\quad \frac{\Gamma\vdash Q}{\Gamma\vdash P\lor Q}{\lor}R_2 $$
This is complete for the $\{{\leftrightarrow},{\lor},\bot\}$ fragment because the *full* intuitionistic sequent calculus satisfies cut elimination.

To show that this fragment is complete *in expressivity*, express $P\to Q$ as $(P\lor Q)\leftrightarrow Q$ -- this equivalence is intuitionistically valid, and the usual left and right rules for $\to$ are easily built as combinations of the above rules.

Similarly, $\neg P$ is of course equivalent to $P\leftrightarrow \bot$.

For conjunction, contrary to speculation in comments, it turns out that $(P\lor Q)\leftrightarrow(P\leftrightarrow Q)$ is indeed intuitionistically equivalent to $P\land Q$. The difficult direction is to see that the usual ${\land}L$ rule is admissible, which can be done as follows in the above sequent calculus:

$$\begin{array}{rll}
0. & \Gamma,~ P,~ Q \vdash R & \text{premise of derived rule} \\
1. & P\vdash P\lor Q & \text{easy} \\
2. & P\leftrightarrow Q,~ P \vdash Q & \text{easy} \\
3. & (P\lor Q)\leftrightarrow(P\leftrightarrow Q),~ P \vdash Q & 1, 2, {\leftrightarrow}L_2 \\
4. & (P\lor Q)\leftrightarrow(P\leftrightarrow Q),~ Q \vdash P & \text{mutatis mutandis} \\
5. & (P\lor Q)\leftrightarrow(P\leftrightarrow Q) \vdash P\leftrightarrow Q & 3,4, {\leftrightarrow}R \\
6. & P\lor Q \vdash P\lor Q & \text{axiom} \\
7. & \Gamma,~ P\lor Q,~ P\leftrightarrow Q \vdash R & \text{easy consequence of }0 \\
8. & \Gamma,~ (P\lor Q)\leftrightarrow(P\leftrightarrow Q),~ P\lor Q \vdash R & 6,7, {\leftrightarrow}L_2 \\
9. & \Gamma,~ (P\lor Q)\leftrightarrow(P\leftrightarrow Q),~
     (P\lor Q)\leftrightarrow(P\leftrightarrow Q) \vdash R & 5,8, {\leftrightarrow}L_1 \\
10. & \Gamma,~ (P\lor Q)\leftrightarrow(P\leftrightarrow Q) \vdash R & 9, CL
\end{array}$$

(Proof found by exhaustive search!)

---

Or, for those that favor the Curry-Howard isomorphism for intuitionistic proofs, the idea in Haskell-like pseudosyntax for the ${\leftrightarrow}{\lor}{\bot}$ fragment is to replace

```
conj :: (P,Q)
let (x::P,y::Q) = conj
in  <..x..y..>
```

by

```
conj :: (Either P Q) <-> (P <-> Q)
let eq1 :: P <-> Q
    eq1 (x :: P) = let eq2 :: P <-> Q = conj (Left x) in eq2 x
    eq1 (y :: Q) = let eq2 :: P <-> Q = conj (Right y) in eq2 y
    disj :: Either P Q = conj eq1
in case disj of
     Left(x::P) -> let y::Q = eq1 x in <..x..y..>
     Right(y::Q) -> let x::P = eq1 y in <..x..y..>
```

where `P <-> Q` is supposed to behave like a function that can be applied to either `P` or `Q` and produces an output of the opposite type, and disjunction is represented by the standard `Either` type.

Comment: What rules are $\leftrightarrow L$ and $\leftrightarrow R$, exactly?

Comment: @dfeuer: I've added rule names

Comment: Maybe I'm daft, but how does $\Gamma,P,Q\vdash R$ make sense as a premise?

Comment: @dfeuer: The goal here is to construct $$\frac{\Gamma, P, Q\vdash R}{\Gamma,~P\land Q\vdash R}{\land}L$$ as a derived rule. If you just want to derive $P\land Q\vdash P$, replace $R$ with $P$ and let $\Gamma$ be empty.

Comment: I've read over it a bit more carefully now. It appears the key steps are really 3–5, with the rest all being build-up and tear-down. Is that about right?

Comment: @dfeuer: I think so, though "key steps" if of course subjective. It could be argued that the inference that concludes 9 is also pretty key: "Now that we have proved $P\leftrightarrow Q$, our encoding of $P\land Q$ tells us that we also have $P\lor Q$". To my mind, that's when we start knowing something _positive_. But on the other hand it was easy from the start to see that we could do that if we could only prove $P\leftrightarrow Q$, so steps 3-5 are indeed what required _inspiration_ (or rather, for me, brute force) to find.